# Out of memory in GAE devserver

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, google-api, google-apps

I am working on a directory application using Google Apps API to store all data(users, groups, org units) from APIs into data store and then query the data store to display the user for searching and viewing.

I am doing the loading of users and groups using tasks. The approach that I am following is to read data from API and then create an entity of every user in a loop and then look for nextPageToken and if it is not null, assign another task of loading the users. The same approach is being followed for groups and OU as well.

Now the problem is if I run it on a google domain having 2k users, it works fine, however when I run it on environment having 90K users, it works fine till it reaches 12-13k users and then it stops responding and tasks stop responding and the memory usage on my machine goes higher and this is the case on my local devserver as I havent deployed it yet on appengine.

There is lots of backend code following the approach that I described above, however I am not sure what to provide here, so please ask questions that you may think could be causing the problem. I will paste the snippet here, whatever is asked for!

The actual production server will have double the amount of users , i.e. close to 200K, which concerns me a lot. Please help!

Comment: Have you tried running this on their servers? It could be hitting some bottlenecks on the test server.

Comment: @gaurav-sachdeva if you are using Task Queues to do the work, what happens when you decrease the throughput? If you try setting the `max-concurrent-requests` value to one?

Comment: Unfortunately, setting max-concurrent-requests is not an option as it would take forever to complete 200k users.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to create all users / entities in one loop and then save all in one step, that is unnecessary and (as you ran into it) requires a lot more memory.

Instead break it into smaller groups, e.g. limit your cycle to 100 entities for example, save those 100 and continue. That way the instance handling the request doesn't have to keep several thousands of entities in memory.

You mentioned you are doing this with tasks. Your bottleneck is memory. By decreasing the number of entities created and saved by a task, you effectively will increase the number of requests to do the job, and since there will be less entities handled by a task, you will increase not just the number of requests but also the request rate. This will result in less memory usage by tasks, and this will suggest to the GAE platform to spin up new instances more often which means you will have overall more memory.

So handling less entities in a task is a good and easy way to decrease your memory requirement.

Comment: I am running the loading of users/groups using tasks and each task only processes 500 users, not more. I believe, 500 shouldnt be too much to increase the memory load. Could it be something else?

Comment: @GauravSachdeva I would lower that 500 limit (e.g. to 100) because saving 500 entities might cause reaching some datastore timeout. But theoretically it should work with 500. Maybe you're not clearing the list in which you store them?

Comment: Every time in every new task a new list of objects is created based on response from the server, so where exactly should I clear it?

Comment: In this case you shouldn't, but I didn't know that because you haven't posted any code.

Comment: @GauravSachdeva Edited the question, see reasoning why you should try to handle less entities in your tasks.